# My tex file fails to compile correctly by ignoring all and every single citation in the document

Tags: bibtex, natbib, aastex

I have been working on a long overleaf document for a long time. Here is the overall layout without including any text. I never had any issue with citations in the document.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,floatfix]{aastex62}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}


\bibliographystyle{aasjournal}
\bibliography{References} 


\end{document}
```

However, just very suddently without adding any new citation or anything else to the document, I started receiving ~150 warnings of the following form literally for every single `\cite` or `\citep` I have in the documnet leaving the final compiled document all including ???? inside the text and no reference page at all:

```
Package natbib Warning:Citation       file.tex
```

I have checked for all possible issues mentioned at ([Citation XXX on page XXX undefined on input line XXX](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Errors/Citation_XXX_on_page_XXX_undefined_on_input_line_XXX)). Nothing applies to my case. What could have gone wrong? I truly do not want to include my entire document as nothing was changed to produce this warning; it was all sudden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing/broken .bib file, some of the intermediate files got corrupted/truncated, ...

With no clear, *complete* details (a MWE, minimal (non)working example, here including the bibliography file and citations), we can only file it under "yet another unexplained problem, probable user error; no details, closed".

Comment: @thank you, I had to create another project on overleaf and build it from scratch adding one section at a time to see where I have the problem. Interesting, there was no problem. But you will right! the file somehow was corrupted and there was no other way for me to figure this out.